# can anyone suggest to me LARS algorithm code?

Tags: matlab

please I need someone to give me LARS MATLAB code, because I have one but there is an error when I run the code. The code gives me the following error:

> Input argument "X" is undefined. Error in ==> lars at 46 [n,p] =
>   size(X); this code

```
function [beta, A, mu, C, c, gamma] = lars(X, Y, option, t, standardize)
% Least Angle Regression (LAR) algorithm.
% Ref: Efron et. al. (2004) Least angle regression. Annals of Statistics.
% option = 'lar' implements the vanilla LAR algorithm (default);
% option = 'lasso' solves the lasso path with a modified LAR algorithm.
% t -- a vector of increasing positive real numbers. If given, LARS 
% returns the solution at t.
%
% Output:
% A -- a sequence of indices that indicate the order of variable         
% beta: history of estimated LARS coefficients;
% mu -- history of estimated mean vector;
% C -- history of maximal current absolute corrrelations;
% c -- history of current corrrelations;
% gamma: history of LARS step size.
% Note: history is traced by rows. If t is given, beta is just the
% estimated coefficient vector at the constraint ||beta||_1 = t.
%
% Remarks:
% 1. LARS is originally proposed to estimate a sparse coefficient vector 
% a noisy over-determined linear system. LARS outputs estimates for all
% shrinkage/constraint parameters (homotopy).
%
% 2. LARS is well suited for Basis Pursuit (BP) purpose in the real 
% automatically terminates when the current correlations for inactive 
% all zeros. The recovered coefficient vector is the last column of beta 
% with the *lasso* option. Hence, this function provides a fast and 
% efficient solution for the ell_1 minimization problem. 
% Ref: Donoho and Tsaig (2006). Fast solution of ell_1 norm minimization 

if nargin < 5, standardize = true; end
if nargin < 4, t = Inf; end
if nargin < 3, option = 'lar'; end

if strcmpi(option, 'lasso'), lasso = 1; else, lasso = 0; end

eps = 1e-10;    % Effective zero

[n,p] = size(X);
if standardize,
    X = normalize(X);
    Y = Y-mean(Y);
end
m = min(p,n-1); % Maximal number of variables in the final active set
T = length(t);

beta = zeros(1,p);
mu = zeros(n,1);    % Mean vector
gamma = []; % LARS step lengths
A = [];
Ac = 1:p;
nVars = 0;
signOK = 1;
i = 0;
mu_old = zeros(n,1);
t_prev = 0;
beta_t = zeros(T,p);
ii = 1;
tt = t;

% LARS loop
while nVars < m,
    i = i+1;
    c = X'*(Y-mu);  % Current correlation
    C = max(abs(c));    % Maximal current absolute correlation
    if C < eps || isempty(t), break; end    % Early stopping criteria
    if 1 == i, addVar = find(C==abs(c)); end
    if signOK,
        A = [A,addVar]; % Add one variable to active set
        nVars = nVars+1;
    end
    s_A = sign(c(A));
    Ac = setdiff(1:p,A);    % Inactive set
    nZeros = length(Ac);
    X_A = X(:,A);
    G_A = X_A'*X_A; % Gram matrix
    invG_A = inv(G_A);
    L_A = 1/sqrt(s_A'*invG_A*s_A);
    w_A = L_A*invG_A*s_A;   % Coefficients of equiangular vector u_A
    u_A = X_A*w_A;  % Equiangular vector
    a = X'*u_A; % Angles between x_j and u_A
    beta_tmp = zeros(p,1);
    gammaTest = zeros(nZeros,2);
    if nVars == m,
        gamma(i) = C/L_A;   % Move to the least squares projection
    else
        for j = 1:nZeros,
            jj = Ac(j);
            gammaTest(j,:) = [(C-c(jj))/(L_A-a(jj)), (C+c(jj))/(L_A+a(jj))];
        end
        [gamma(i) min_i min_j] = minplus(gammaTest);
        addVar = unique(Ac(min_i));
    end
    beta_tmp(A) = beta(i,A)' + gamma(i)*w_A;    % Update coefficient estimates
    % Check the sign feasibility of lasso
    if lasso,
        signOK = 1;
        gammaTest = -beta(i,A)'./w_A;
        [gamma2 min_i min_j] = minplus(gammaTest);
        if gamma2 < gamma(i),   % The case when sign consistency gets violated
            gamma(i) = gamma2;
            beta_tmp(A) = beta(i,A)' + gamma(i)*w_A;    % Correct the coefficients
            beta_tmp(A(unique(min_i))) = 0;
            A(unique(min_i)) = [];  % Delete the zero-crossing variable (keep the ordering)
            nVars = nVars-1;
            signOK = 0;
        end
    end
    if Inf ~= t(1),
        t_now = norm(beta_tmp(A),1);
        if t_prev < t(1) && t_now >= t(1),
            beta_t(ii,A) = beta(i,A) + L_A*(t(1)-t_prev)*w_A';    % Compute coefficient estimates corresponding to a specific t
            t(1) = [];
            ii = ii+1;
        end
        t_prev = t_now;
    end
    mu = mu_old + gamma(i)*u_A; % Update mean vector
    mu_old = mu;
    beta = [beta; beta_tmp'];
end

if 1 < ii,
    noCons = (tt > norm(beta_tmp,1));
    if 0 < sum(noCons),
        beta_t(noCons,:) = repmat(beta_tmp',sum(noCons),1);
    end
    beta = beta_t;
end


% Normalize columns of X to have mean zero and length one.
function sX = normalize(X)

[n,p] = size(X);
sX = X-repmat(mean(X),n,1);
sX = sX*diag(1./sqrt(ones(1,n)*sX.^2));


% Find the minimum and its index over the (strictly) positive part of X
% matrix
function [m, I, J] = minplus(X)

% Remove complex elements and reset to Inf
[I,J] = find(0~=imag(X));
for i = 1:length(I),
    X(I(i),J(i)) = Inf;
end
 X(X<=0) = Inf;
m = min(min(X));
[I,J] = find(X==m);
```

Comment: What about it isn't working exactly? Also, google "LARS matlab" - there are about a zillion.2 results.

Comment: "Input argument "X" is undefined" --> you need to actually give this code some inputs, don't just hit the shiny green run button.

Comment: could you know , input like what?

Comment: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-basics.html  Until you understand at least the basics of how functions work, there's no point downloading random code from the internet and trying to make it run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make some arrays of data:

```
n=100
v1=rand(n,1);
v2=rand(n,1);
v3=rand(n,1);
```

make a linear combination of the data

```
Y=2*v1+3*v2+5*v3;
```

make a noisy matrix out of the data:

```
X=[v1 v2 v3];
X=X+rand(size(X))/10;
```

run the function

```
beta=lars(X, Y)
```

beta should be [2,3,5]